# Setting option is missing in Ubuntu 22 after few days

Tags: system-settings

The setting menu was available for few days in Ubuntu 22, however after using it for 1 week the option is now not visible. This happened twice. At first I reinstalled the Ubuntu 22. Again it got missing. Can someone help me regarding this issue ?

Comment: I assume when you say "Ubuntu 22" that you mean "Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, on the desktop"? When you say "Setting" it's a bit vague. Can you be more specific what setting is "not visible". Perhaps with a screenshot or photograph attached to the question above?

Comment: Or do you mean Ubuntu Core 22?   Ubuntu Core 22 is a *snap* only flavor of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server intended for *headless* operation, as are all *year* format products (the *year.month* products like 22.04 can be used as desktop or server system. *year* products being intended for devices or cloud use only)

Comment: Can you open the Settings app from the terminal with `gnome-control-center` ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.